# How to set font dynamically based on locale in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, locale

I have a project with 3 different locales and I need to use another font for Vietnamese locale. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm asking people how to do it, what do you mean by asking me to show the code? Basically I config my locales by following the Rails official guide on locales and I loaded my fonts using CSS font-face.

Comment: btw which part of code do you want me to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the template, you can change the font based on locale by simply using the locale name as a CSS selector, as follows:

```
<body class="<%= I18n.locale %>">
 ...
</body>
```

and in your SASS file:

```
body {
  .en {
    $main-font: "Verdana"
   }
  .cn {
    $main-font: "Microsoft_YaHei247019"
   }
}
```

Comment: damn it is this easy